# How to use Regular Expressions inside treePatterns?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am working with the example about Parse Tree Matching and XPath shown [here](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parse+Tree+Matching+and+XPath). More specifically, I was trying to understand how the following code works:

```
// assume we are parsing Java
ParserRuleContext tree = parser.compilationUnit();
String xpath = "//blockStatement/*"; // get children of blockStatement
String treePattern = "int <Identifier> = <expression>;";
ParseTreePattern p =
parser.compileParseTreePattern(treePattern,   
ExprParser.RULE_localVariableDeclarationStatement);
List<ParseTreeMatch> matches = p.findAll(tree, xpath);
System.out.println(matches);
```

What I wanted to ask is if we can have regular expressions inside the treePattern string?

For example, I want to write a pattern which identifies all the localVariableDeclarations inside a for loop.

I would like to be able to identify the following code:

```
for (Object o : list) {
    int tempVariable=0;
    if (  o.id ==12) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

The way I have written the pattern (which works) to identify this code is as follows:

```
    String pattern3 = " for  ( <className1:type> <localName1:Identifier> : <listName1:expression>  ) { <localVariables1:localVariableDeclarationStatement> "
            + "if (<parameter1:expression>.<identifier1:Identifier> == <value1:primary> ) <block1:statement> }";
```

However, if I have more than one local variables, the pattern doesn't match. I tried to add a '*' at the end as it would happen in the grammar file, but I get an 
* invalid tag error.

```
  <localVariables1:localVariableDeclarationStatement>*
```

Of course I can also add a pattern with two localVariableDeclarationStatement statements, but this again means that I have to create many different patterns for each number of local variables that I want to identify:

```
  <localVariables1:localVariableDeclarationStatement> <localVariables2:localVariableDeclarationStatement> and identify the pattern with
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, we don't support repeated elements within the patterns. I thought about that but it essentially means making yet another parser generator whereas static patterns like that are fairly easy to match. It's possible to build one of these, as the last version of ANTLR had tree grammars where you could in fact specify  the grammatical structure of subtrees. Until we decide what sort of enhancement to the patterns we can make, I suggest you get creative.

In your specific case, find all of the localVariableDeclarations within for loops as you are doing now and then use a small bit of code to walk that list to identify the contiguous sequences (they are all siblings) and the ones terminated by that particular IF pattern.  Would that work?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I will try what you suggested.

Comment: I would just like to add support for expressions like this!  For example imagine java modifiers to a field declaration.  You should be able to go something like "<modifier>* <memberDeclaration>" so you don't have to catch all the versions of it to know if you are in a field vs a static block.